# ipsec/strongswan - how to use remote router as local gateway using the route command

Tags: routing, strongswan

Ok, this should be an easy one, but its driving me nuts.

> Scenario:
>
> Site A (San Francisco)
> Site B (Colombia)

Both sites are connected successfully via IPSec (openswan, debian 8):

> SiteA---------------SiteB
> 10.2.0.1 <==inet==> 10.3.0.1

I can successfully PING 10.3.0.1 from SiteA.... also, 10 phone extensions in the 10.3.0.0 subnet connect to SiteA. Sweet, no problem.

However please note 10.3.0.1 **IS NOT LISTED** as a route anywhere under the SiteA's kernel routing table, but If i do a ping from 10.2.0.1, it works.

> THE PROBLEM:

Ok. I just added a SIP router 10.11.208.93 in SiteB. SiteA needs to be 10.11.208.94 and has to be able to reach 10.11.208.93 via 10.3.0.1. I have added this bridge successfully on 10.3.0.1 in SiteB.

When i try to create the static route to the SIP router via 10.3.0.1 in SiteA, the route command says the host is not reachable. But i can ping 10.3.0.1 from SiteA.

> ## ip route add -net 10.11.208.92/30 via 10.3.0.1
>
> SIOADDR: Host unreachable

Question is: where/how the hell is strongswan(ipsec) configuring linux routing table to reach 10.3.0.1 via the tunnel ??? it doesn't show on the routing table.

If i can ping 10.3.0.1, why can´t i use it as a route to reach a subnet behind it, having a working tunnel already?

Answer (score 4):

strongSwan installs routes in routing table 220 by default. You can see these with `ip route list table 220`.

Adding a route won't get your traffic tunneled though. IPsec is policy based (you can see these with `ip xfrm policy`), so if you have an IPsec policy that allows traffic between e.g. 10.2.0.0/16 and 10.3.0.0/16 only matching traffic is actually tunneled. Which is not the case for packets sent from 10.11.208.94 to 10.11.208.93. Therefore, you have to explicitly add a tunnel that covers these IPs.