# Strongswan IPsec site-to-site on Gcloud

Tags: linux-networking, ipsec, strongswan, gcloud

I am trying to initialise an IPsec tunnel between an Ubuntu VM on Google Cloud and a remote site.

The connection is correctly established but from the Ubuntu machine on Google Cloud I cannot reach a host on the remote network (172.17.20.25).

**Gcloud:**

Public IP: 50.50.50.50

Private IP: 10.132.0.63/32

**Remote site:**

Public IP: 100.100.100.100

Remote private network: 172.17.20.0/16

*ipsec.conf*

```
config setup
        charondebug="all"
        uniqueids=yes
conn intacloud-to-tper
        type=tunnel
        auto=start
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
        leftid=50.50.50.50
        leftsubnet=10.132.0.62/32
        right=100.100.100.100
        rightsubnet=172.17.20.0/16 
        ike=aes-sha1-modp2048
        esp=aes-sha1
        aggressive=no
        keyingtries=%forever
        ikelifetime=28800s
        lifetime=3600s
        dpddelay=30s
        dpdtimeout=120s
        dpdaction=restart
```

*ip route show table 220*

```
172.17.0.0/16 via 10.132.0.1 dev ens4 proto static src 10.132.0.62
```

*ipsec statusall*

```
    Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.9.5, Linux 6.2.0-1019-gcp, x86_64):
  uptime: 2 hours, since Jan 24 17:36:07 2024
  malloc: sbrk 3100672, mmap 0, used 1403424, free 1697248
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 3
  loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Listening IP addresses:
  10.132.0.62
Connections:
site-to-site:  %any...100.100.100.100  IKEv2, dpddelay=30s
site-to-site:   local:  [50.50.50.50] uses pre-shared key authentication
site-to-site:   remote: [100.100.100.100] uses pre-shared key authentication
site-to-site:   child:  10.132.0.62/32 === 172.17.0.0/16 TUNNEL, dpdaction=restart
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
site-to-site[1]: ESTABLISHED 2 hours ago, 10.132.0.62[50.50.50.50]...100.100.100.100[100.100.100.100]
site-to-site[1]: IKEv2 SPIs: -, pre-shared key reauthentication in 5 hours
site-to-site[1]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048
site-to-site{4}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: cb5b6fdd_i 932ca574_o
site-to-site{4}:  AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96, 0 bytes_i, 0 bytes_o, rekeying in 27 minutes
site-to-site{4}:   10.132.0.62/32 === 172.17.0.0/16
```

*ip xfrm policy*

```
src 10.132.0.63/32 dst 172.17.0.0/16 
    dir out priority 375423 ptype main 
    tmpl src 10.132.0.63 dst 100.100.100.100
        proto esp spi 0xbb44a532 reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 172.17.0.0/16 dst 10.132.0.63/32 
    dir fwd priority 375423 ptype main 
    tmpl src 100.100.100.100 dst 10.132.0.63
        proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
```

I cannot understand whether there might be a configuration problem or whether the problem might be in the configuration of the remote site

Comment: This does not look correct ` leftsubnet=10.132.0.62/32`. What is the result of `ipsec statusall`?

Comment: @JohnHanley output of `ip addr`:
`2: ens4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:84:00:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.132.0.62/32 metric 100 scope global dynamic ens4
       valid_lft 75466sec preferred_lft 75466sec
  `

Comment: Please edit your question to include new information. Do not use comments, images or links to external resources.

Comment: I also do not think the route is correct. That route will send traffic to `10.132.0.1`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry you are right , I edited the post.

The route was automatically added by strongswan, even to me it does not look correct


However, I would not know how to edit it

Comment: see this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/744935/437769)

Comment: %Thank you John, the policies seem correct to me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, in addition to opening UDP ports 500 and 4500 on Google Cloud Firewall it is necessary to add the ESP protocol

Protocols and ports

udp:500

udp:4500

esp